# Cannot Persist Store Connected Components - React-Redux Tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, tdd, react-redux

I cannot figure out why this is not working:

**-spec.js**

```
it.only('passes props to children', () => {
    const state = {
        company: {
            name: 'Company A'
        }
    },
        store = fakeStore(state),
        container = <HomePageContainer store={store} />;

    const homePageContainer = shallow(container),
        homePage = homePageContainer.find(HomePage);

    expect(homePage.props.company.name).to.equal(state.company.name)
});

const fakeStore = state => {
    return {
        default: () => {},
        subscribe: () => {},
        dispatch: () => {},
        getState: () => { return { state };
        },
    };
};
```

**HomePageContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import HomePage from '../../client/components/HomePage';

export const mapStateToProps = state => {
    company: state.company
}

export { HomePage }
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomePage);
```

**HomePage.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

export default class HomePage extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div className='homepage'>
                {/*{this.props.company.name}*/}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I'm getting this type error because props.**company** is undefined so for some reason it's not persisting state to :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

That error is relating to the assert when it's trying to read `expect(homePage.props.company.name)`

I notice that when putting a breakpoint inside mapStateToProps, that it's not picking up the state object from the store still for some reason:

[image]

I know you can pass just the store via props...and if there's nothing in the context, connect() will be able to find it via the store prop.  For example in another test suite, this passes just fine:

```
it('shallow render container and dive into child', () => {
    const container = shallow(<ExampleContainer store={fakeStore({})}/>);

    expect(container.find(Example).dive().text()).to.equal('Andy');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem

At this line you pass the store as a prop into `<HomePageContainer>`:

```
// ...
container = <HomePageContainer store={store} />;
// ...
```

But `connect()` needs the store via context.

And you must wrap the object you want to return in `mapStateToProps` in parenthese.

## Solution

You can use `shallow()` to make the store available as a context property.

```
it.only('passes props to children', () => {
    const state = {
        company: {
            name: 'Company A'
        }
    };
    const store = fakeStore(state);

    const homePageContainer = shallow(
        <HomePageContainer />,
        // Make the store available via context
        { context: { store } }
    );

    const homePage = homePageContainer.find(HomePage);
    expect(homePage.props().company.name).to.equal(state.company.name)
});
```

Updated `mapStateToProps`:

```
export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    company: state.company
});
```

Comment: I was pretty sure that if you don't use Provider (or setting context in options for enzyme), that connect would just pick it up from straight props...?  I also tried using <Provider /> with still no luck

Comment: No, `connect` depends on the store which is passed via the context.

Comment: still not working:  store = fakeStore(state), container = <HomePageContainer />;  const homePageContainer = shallow(container, { context: { store } }),

Comment: I disagree that you  -must- pass via context in tests.  You -can-, that's one way, but I've gotten it to pass via straight props before, see my update in a few seconds here that I'll post.  So pretty sure straight prop with no context should be fine, I even get enzyme errors telling me that.  So that's why this is so weird, that this time in this other test suite, it's not working...

Comment: I found the problem. To access the props you might use `wrapper.props()` to get the props object. I will update the answer.

Comment: And you're right: You can pass the store via props to the connected component.

Comment: I feel like it's something with how I'm creating my container component because mapStateToProps is still receiving undefined for state.company

Comment: Another thing I found out that you must wrap the object you want to return in `mapStateToProps` in parenthese: `export const mapStateToProps = state => ({ company: state.company });`.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem was really my helper.

This was passing a object with property "state" in it.  Not what I want.  That would have meant that mapStateToProps would have had to reference the props with state.state.somePropName

```
const fakeStore = (state) => {
    return {
            default: () => {},
            subscribe: () => {},
            dispatch: () => {},
            getState: () => { return { state };
        },
    };
};
```

changed it to this, and now mapStateToProps is working fine, it's able to access it with the props as the root level of the object literal, the object I passed in from my test:

const fakeStore = (state) => ({

```
    default: () => {},
    subscribe: () => {},
    dispatch: () => {},
    getState: () => ({ ...state })
});
```